# How can I check if JSON variable exists or no

Tags: android

I got an error if the content variable not found how I can solve it?

*JSON*

```
{
  "transcript": {
    "text": [
      {
        "content": "Tonight we&#39;re running on the right track",
        "dur": "2",
        "start": "2.649"
      },
      {
        "dur": "0.5",
        "start": "4.649"
      },
      {
        "dur": "0.5",
        "start": "5.149"
      },
      {
        "dur": "0.5",
        "start": "5.649"
      },
      {
        "dur": "0.5",
        "start": "7.1"
      },
      {
        "content": "I know we&#39;re never look back",
        "dur": "1.04",
        "start": "7.6"
      },
      {
        "content": "Oh i",
        "dur": "0.5",
        "start": "12.3"
      },
      {
        "content": "just want to have a good time",
        "dur": "2.16",
        "start": "12.92"
      },
      {
        "content": "Call me or Whatever",
        "dur": "2",
        "start": "15.2"
      },
      {
        "content": "some ### will anything life back",
        "dur": "2.8",
        "start": "17.2"
      },
      {
        "content": "Oh no",
        "dur": "2",
        "start": "20.88"
      },
      {
        "content": "we don&#39;t want to be",
        "dur": "1.2",
        "start": "22.96"
      },
      {
        "content": "Sloomo",
        "dur": "0.8",
        "start": "24.16"
      },
      {
        "content": "so my #### says",
        "dur": "1.44",
        "start": "25.52"
      },
      {
        "content": "Let&#39;s Go",
        "dur": "2",
        "start": "26.96"
      },
      {
        "content": "To the beat and sweet and sweet",
        "dur": "2",
        "start": "28.96"
      },
      {
        "content": "and see me like",
        "dur": "2",
        "start": "30.96"
      },
      {
        "content": "see me like",
        "dur": "2",
        "start": "33.56"
      },
      {
        "content": "Party like",
        "dur": "2",
        "start": "35.96"
      },
      {
        "content": "Breaking up\nTo the beat like see me like",
        "dur": "2.34",
        "start": "38.26"
      },
      {
        "content": "Pencil or no pencil pencil?",
        "dur": "1.26",
        "start": "48.08"
      },
      {
        "content": "Pencil.",
        "dur": "1.16",
        "start": "51.92"
      },
      {
        "content": "Do you want Steve in the background?",
        "dur": "2",
        "start": "58.04"
      },
      {
        "content": "I don&#39;t know. Does he deserve it?",
        "dur": "3.14",
        "start": "61.72"
      },
      {
        "content": "My phone buzzered every time you tagged me.",
        "dur": "3.44",
        "start": "65.1"
      },
      {
        "content": "Maybe someday, I&#39;ll let you be my real boyfriend.",
        "dur": "2.42",
        "start": "75.76"
      },
      {
        "content": "You love it.",
        "dur": "2",
        "start": "78.18"
      },
      {
        "content": "Free phone ? Once I hit 2,000.",
        "dur": "2",
        "start": "83.36"
      },
      {
        "content": "&quot;That&#39;s that&#39;s totally doable.&quot; &quot;Just a matter of time.&quot; &quot;Your, your first brand deal.&quot;",
        "dur": "6.22",
        "start": "86.68"
      },
      {
        "content": "Drop this off at the library, I hate going in there. Of course. Deuces!",
        "dur": "6.64",
        "start": "95.66"
      },
      {
        "content": "Jen ?",
        "dur": "0.5",
        "start": "102.56"
      },
      {
        "content": "We don&#39;t say that anymore.",
        "dur": "2",
        "start": "105.02"
      },
      {
        "content": "Right. See ya!",
        "dur": "2",
        "start": "108.38"
      },
      {
        "content": "So, what do you think?",
        "dur": "2",
        "start": "115.58"
      },
      {
        "content": "&quot;Who did them?&quot; &quot;Me!&quot; &quot;How old were you?&quot; &quot;I worked on &#39;em this week.&quot;",
        "dur": "6.52",
        "start": "122.84"
      },
      {
        "content": "Oh.",
        "dur": "0.84",
        "start": "130.96"
      },
      {
        "content": "Yeah, I&#39;m thinking of changing electives, next term maybe taking art.",
        "dur": "4.4",
        "start": "133.2"
      },
      {
        "content": "Okay.",
        "dur": "3.21",
        "start": "149.42"
      },
      {
        "content": "Uhm, no.",
        "dur": "2",
        "start": "152.63"
      },
      {
        "content": "&quot;I&#39;m just starting.&quot; &quot;And now it&#39;s time to stop.&quot; &quot;This...isn&#39;t you.&quot;",
        "dur": "7.52",
        "start": "156.08"
      },
      {
        "content": "These are bad.",
        "dur": "2",
        "start": "164.93"
      },
      {
        "content": "Okay.",
        "dur": "1.89",
        "start": "169.7"
      },
      {
        "content": "You have to stay in the classes that I&#39;m taking. I need you there. I mean...",
        "dur": "5.18",
        "start": "171.59"
      },
      {
        "content": "Who else is gonna tell me how pretty I am?",
        "dur": "2.059",
        "start": "177.68"
      },
      {
        "content": "Yeah",
        "dur": "2",
        "start": "181.16"
      },
      {
        "content": "&quot;Probably everybody&quot; &quot;Probably, but still I can&#39;t have an artsy boyfriend.&quot;",
        "dur": "6.11",
        "start": "183.44"
      },
      {
        "content": "So I am the boyfriend ?",
        "dur": "2",
        "start": "191.84"
      },
      {
        "content": "I know we&#39;re so cute together. I&#39;m just contouring. *laughs* He&#39;s five months older.",
        "dur": "7.489",
        "start": "199.88"
      },
      {
        "content": "I straighten my hair?",
        "dur": "2",
        "start": "209.93"
      },
      {
        "content": "I am not telling you where I live.",
        "dur": "2.149",
        "start": "214.19"
      },
      {
        "content": "&quot;Hey, Nikki. Have you seen the remote?&quot; &quot;I don&#39;t watch TV, Dad!&quot;",
        "dur": "4.4",
        "start": "217.7"
      },
      {
        "content": "Your mom&#39;s missing the Kardashians.",
        "dur": "2",
        "start": "222.77"
      },
      {
        "content": "&quot;Mom&#39;s missing the Kardashians?&quot;",
        "dur": "2.92",
        "start": "225.4"
      },
      {
        "content": "&quot;Yeah, can you help us find the remote please.&quot;"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

*Code*

```
    try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(xmlToJson));
            JSONObject transcript = jsonObject.getJSONObject("transcript");
            JSONArray jsonArray = transcript.getJSONArray("text");
            for (int x = 0; x < jsonArray.length(); x++) {
                test += " " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(x).getString("content") + " ";
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

*Error*

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for content
```

I got an error in this line

```
test += " " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(x).getString("content") + " ";
```

thanks a lot.

Comment: tried to carefully read [JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject) official documentation? if so, whats unclear?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject#has(java.lang.String)

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I tried (has and null) but without result.

Comment: show how you tried, and what exactly `without result` means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json you have has the entries

```
  {
    "dur": "0.5",
    "start": "4.649"
  },
  {
    "dur": "0.5",
    "start": "5.149"
  },
  {
    "dur": "0.5",
    "start": "5.649"
  },
  {
    "dur": "0.5",
    "start": "7.1"
  },
  {
    "content": "I know we&#39;re never look back",
    "dur": "1.04",
    "start": "7.6"
  }
```

Some of those entries does not have the variable `content` in them so it throws an error when it tries to access it.
What you can do to solve it is add an if check.

```
for (int x = 0; x < jsonArray.length(); x++) {
             JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(x);
             if(jsonObj.has("content"){
               test += " " + jsonObj.getString("content") + " ";
              }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for leave full example , I use `if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(x).has("content"))`

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple ways to do this,

I suggest that instead of checking it, just use the following to get the value

```
optString()
```

instead of getString, it will not throw an exception when the content does not exist

If you still want to check, JSONObject has a method

```
boolean has(String name)
```

this method will tell you if the key is present

The following code should work fine

```
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(xmlToJson));
        JSONObject transcript = jsonObject.getJSONObject("transcript");
        JSONArray jsonArray = transcript.getJSONArray("text");

        JSONObject temp;

        for (int x = 0; x < jsonArray.length(); x++) {
            temp = jsonArray.getJSONObject(x);

            if(temp.has("content")){
               test += " " + temp.getString("content") + " ";
            }


        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Alternative approach i would use is:

```
        try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(xmlToJson));
        JSONObject transcript = jsonObject.getJSONObject("transcript");
        JSONArray jsonArray = transcript.getJSONArray("text");



        for (int x = 0; x < jsonArray.length(); x++) {

            test += " " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(x).optString("content") + " ";

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I tried use `has` but same result , please edit my code above

Answer (score 0):

You can use [has](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#has-java.lang.String-) to check availability

```
.has(name)
```

And you can check nullity with

```
.get(name).isJsonNull
```

I usually use a BaseDeserializer to check parameters

```
open class BaseDeserializer {

    fun check(json: JsonObject, name: String): Boolean {
        return hashValue(json, name) && checkValue(json, name)
    }

    private fun checkValue(json: JsonObject, name: String): Boolean {
        return !json.get(name).isJsonNull
    }

    private fun hashValue(json: JsonObject, name: String): Boolean {
        return json.has(name)
    }
}
```

**Update**

Updated the given example.

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(xmlToJson));
    JSONObject transcript = jsonObject.getJSONObject("transcript");
    JSONArray jsonArray = transcript.getJSONArray("text");
    for (int x = 0; x < jsonArray.length(); x++) {
        JSONObject item = jsonArray.getJSONObject(x);
        if(check(item, "content") {
            test += " " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(x).getString("content") + " ";
        }
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Also `.isJsonNull` is the equivalent in Kotlin for `.isJsonNull()` over a `JsonElement` type

Comment: I can't find `isJsonNull` and I tried use `has` but same result , please edit my code above

Answer (score 0):

try to use like

So try to use parse data with example `jsonObject.optJsonObject("LatLng")` , `optString()`

Use `not null` condition also

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(xmlToJson));
        JSONObject transcript = jsonObject.getJSONObject("transcript");
        JSONArray jsonArray = transcript.getJSONArray("text");
        for (int x = 0; x < jsonArray.length(); x++) {
                   if(jsonObj.has("content"){jsonArray.getJSONObject(x).getString("content") + " ";}
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: It will still throw an error.. You cannot check if a variable is null if it does not exist, :)